# jQuery addClass with prepended name based on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, element

I can add a class to a form element simply by doing something like this:

```
$("input").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Essentially that grabs the form value and adds it to the element as a class. Probably fine in most cases but sometimes the values will be numbers. So that leaves me with something like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="amount-5" name="submitted" value="50" class="form-radio 50">
```

I suppose then, I could target with CSS as `.form-radio.50` but it probably would be better to prepend some text in front of the added value class.  Ideally

```
<input type="radio" id="amount-5" name="submitted" value="50" class="form-radio radio-50">
```

I tried:

```
$("input").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass($('radio-class-' + this).attr("value"));
});
```

... and that did not work. I'm out of ideas. [Here's my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/9qwSV/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually pretty close, but you can simply work with strings like so:

```
$("input").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('radio-class-' + $(this).attr("value"));
});
```

or

```
$("input").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass($(this).attr("type") + '-' + $(this).attr("value"));
});
```

So you can also differ by `input type` :)

Just to give a brief explanation why what you did does not work:

```
$(this).addClass( $('radio-class-' + this).attr("value") );
```

$() is a selector (in most cases), so you are basically selecting an element of type `radio-class-[this]` which does not exist. Also, **`this`** is the reference of the current object and i believe cannot be transformed into a string by writing `'radio-class-'+this`. Hope that makes sense to you. Just select the object: `$(this)` turns `this` into a `jQuery object` sothat you can access jQuery functions, like `.attr()` which will return a value to use as string